# Use QGIS field calculator raster_value() function inside Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I need to use the raster_value() function (from field calculator) inside a graphical modeler workflow.
The function works if the raster is already loaded on QGIS, and then calling the raster name on the function.
But I need to have an input raster on the model (which might not have been preloaded on qgis) and then use the raster_value() over this raster.

Is there a way to map an inputted raster on modeler and then use the raster_value() function?

I'm using Win10 and QGIS 3.10